# Is it ok to allow tab skipping of terms and privacy links on a registration page?

Tags: registration, hyperlinks, tabindex

I have a registration page containing the following fields, links and button:

- Name:
- Email:
- Password:
- CAPTCHA (third party):
- privacy **link** for CAPTCHA (third party)
- Site Terms **link**
- Register **button**

To allow faster sign up for users, I am contemplating of allowing users who tab through the fields to be able to skip the links with `<a href="link" tabindex=-1>`. Is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not OK.

You would create difficulties :

- For people who want to go to one of these links.
- And for people who want to skip one of these links.

What about people wanting to go to one of these links ? You would make this difficult for these people. Remember that `tabindex` is not only for faster wandering in the form, `tabindex` is there for [accessibility](http://www.w3.org/WAI/), some people need it to work properly.

The `tabindex` order and the visual order of the fields must have a minimum of consistency. Imagine a user traversing the form with the Tab key ( <kbd>⇥</kbd> ). The user is at the *CAPTCHA* field and wants to go to *Register*. The user will press Tab three times, expecting to land on the button *Register*. But, with your trick, this would be broken. The user would be puzzled. By wanting to make registration easier, you would have made it more difficult. *Hell is paved with good intentions.*

The good approach is simple :

Put the `tabindex` values in natural order. The users who want to skip the two links will skip them.

Comment: Ok, I guess I have to think of other ways. Thanks.